# Obtain percentiles from an image in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

Suppose I have a 1-band image that represents a species' predicted density and distribution. I'd like to be able to spatially define regions based on density. For instance I'd like to extract pixels that represent the top 10% of of the population. That is, identify the largest valued pixels that when summed are 10% of the total sum of all pixels. Or top 20%, top 30% and so on.

I don't know if this is the best way but in my mind I see the workflow as the following possibility: 1) convert image to array, 2) sort those values from min to max and calculate a cumulative sum, 4) convert back to an image and divide by the maximum value...now any pixel value greater than .9 represents a pixel in the top 10%.

This is the script I've been playing with.

https://code.earthengine.google.com/23ea182e407ed56f8a822ca85dd80d31

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `.percentile` reducer in combination with `.reduceRegion` to get the percentile values of all pixels within your study area.

With those you can mask values higher/lower than the desired percentile.

Here is an example calculating the percentiles at reduced resolution of 300m and masking the top 70%: https://code.earthengine.google.com/1ed53b53c8712fad7bedbc031c0022e2

```js
var abundance_perc = bird_abundance.reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.percentile([10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90]), geometry, 300)
print(abundance_perc)

var top70 = bird_abundance.gte(ee.Number(abundance_perc.get("landcover_p70")))

Map.addLayer(top70, {min:0, max:10}, "top70")
```